# I'm having a scope issue with a javascript function

Tags: javascript, scope

The variable `checkedones` is not passing to the AJAX.Updater.

The item.value is reporting a value so I know that there should be something there, however I'm just left with t pland when I get to the last alert.

How can this be fixed/improved?

```
    function sendemail(){
        var checkedones='';
        var i= $$('.emailer');
        i.each(function(item)
                {

                   if(item.checked){
                    alert(item.value);
                    alert(item.checked);
                    var checkedones = checkedones + item.value + ',';   
                  }
                }
        )
        alert(checkedones);
        new Ajax.Updater('asdfa', 'pages/domailing.php', {
     method:'post',evalScripts:'true' ,parameters: {
  subject1:$('subject1').value,
subject2:$('subject2').value,
body:tinyMCE.get('emailbody').getContent(),
value:checkedones},
evalJS:'force',
onComplete:function(){}
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing: `var checkedones = checkedones + item.value + ',';`

to: `checkedones += (item.value + ',');`

you've re-declared by using `var` inside the loop.

Comment: Brilliant. And much more elegant. thanks for the quick response.